# Way to tell if a section of the page is visible to the user?

Tags: javascript

So I have a JS function that displays a widget at the bottom of the page.  The JS function makes a call to the server to get information to display but I have a theory that most of the people on certain pages never scroll down to even see the widget so i don't want to waste the bandwidth and cycles to render it if it's not going to be seen.  Is there a way I can load it when it comes into view?  As in, if the user scrolls down to Y then the JS function loads up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking for:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/

Here is the demo page for the above:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dnspinger/

Quoting from the above source:

This would tell you if the user is at the bottom of the page (hence new content has to be loaded). It uses [jQuery.](http://jquery.com)

```
if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
{
   // do your loading content code
}
```

**EDIT**

If your widget is to be located somewhere else, you could do something like this:

```
if  ($('#widget').position().top == $(window).scrollTop())
{
   // do your loading within the widget here
}
```

This would tell you if the scrolled position is where the widget is located.

Comment: Cool, what if it's not at the bottom of the page though?  The widget is placed in a random location on different pages so it could be in the middle.

Comment: One note, with jQuery the .position() is relative to the offsetParent.  So if you've got an element within a position:relative or position:absolute element, you're going to have to take the parent element's position into account.  If you don't, you'll notice your position() coordinates are too high up on the page.